# Checking an assembly for a strong name

Tags: c#, security, strongname

Is it possible to check if a dynamically loaded assembly has been signed with a specific strong name?

Is it enough / secure to compare the values returned from **AssemblyName.GetPublicKey()** method?

```
Assembly loaded = Assembly.LoadFile(path);

byte[] evidenceKey = loaded.GetName().GetPublicKey();

if (evidenceKey != null)
{
    byte[] internalKey = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().GetPublicKey();

    if (evidenceKey.SequenceEqual(internalKey))
    {
        return extension;
    }
}
```

Can't this be spoofed? I am not sure if the SetPublicKey() method has any effect on a built assembly, but even the MSDN documentation shows how you can use this on a dynamically generated assembly (reflection emit) so that would mean you could extract the public key from the host application and inject it into an assembly of your own and run mallicious code if the above was the safe-guard, or am I missing something?

Is there a more correct and secure approach? I know if the reversed situation was the scenario, that is, where I wanted to secure the assembly from only being called by signed hosts then I could tag the assembly with the StrongNameIdentityPermission attribute.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no managed way to check the signature of an assembly and checking the public key leaves you vulnerable to spoofing. You will have to use [P/Invoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services) and call the **StrongNameSignatureVerificationEx** function to check the signature

```
[DllImport("mscoree.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern bool StrongNameSignatureVerificationEx(string wszFilePath, bool fForceVerification, ref bool  pfWasVerified);
```

Comment: Whatever you do can leave you to spoofing as the attacker can easily circumvent the check in your assembly and reassemble the modified IL and resign the assembly with his own key.

Comment: When you say that there is no managed way, do you mean that it is technically not possible, or that there isn't a standard library/routine to do it?

Answer (score 15):

Checking strong name using StrongNameSignatureVerificationEx from mscoree.dll is deprecated under .NET 4 according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms232579.aspx.

.NET 4 way of doing it is:

```
var clrStrongName = (IClrStrongName)RuntimeEnvironment.GetRuntimeInterfaceAsObject(new Guid("B79B0ACD-F5CD-409b-B5A5-A16244610B92"), new Guid("9FD93CCF-3280-4391-B3A9-96E1CDE77C8D"));
bool verificationForced;
int result = clrStrongName.StrongNameSignatureVerificationEx(@"PATH\TO\ASSEMBLY.DLL", true, out verificationForced);
if (result == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Valid.");
}



[ComConversionLoss, Guid("9FD93CCF-3280-4391-B3A9-96E1CDE77C8D"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), SecurityCritical]
[ComImport]
internal interface IClrStrongName
{
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.PreserveSig | MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
    int GetHashFromAssemblyFile([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] [In] string pszFilePath, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] [In] [Out] ref int piHashAlg, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 3)] [Out] byte[] pbHash, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] [In] int cchHash, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] out int pchHash);

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.PreserveSig | MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
    int GetHashFromAssemblyFileW([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] [In] string pwzFilePath, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] [In] [Out] ref int piHashAlg, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 3)] [Out] byte[] pbHash, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] [In] int cchHash, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] out int pchHash);

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.PreserveSig | MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
    int GetHashFromBlob([In] IntPtr pbBlob, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] [In] int cchBlob, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] [In] [Out] ref int piHashAlg, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 4)] [Out] byte[] pbHash, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] [In] int cchHash, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] out int pchHash);

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.PreserveSig | MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
    int GetHashFromFile([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] [In] string pszFilePath, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] [In] [Out] ref int piHashAlg, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 3)] [Out] byte[] pbHash, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] [In] int cchHash, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] out int pchHash);

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.PreserveSig | MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
    int GetHashFromFileW([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] [In] string pwzFilePath, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] [In] [Out] ref int piHashAlg, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 3)] [Out] byte[] pbHash, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] [In] int cchHash, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] out int pchHash);

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.PreserveSig | MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
    int GetHashFromHandle([In] IntPtr hFile, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] [In] [Out] ref int piHashAlg, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 3)] [Out] byte[] pbHash, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] [In] int cchHash, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] out int pchHash);

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.PreserveSig | MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    int StrongNameCompareAssemblies([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] [In] string pwzAssembly1, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] [In] string pwzAssembly2, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] out int dwResult);

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.PreserveSig | MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
    int StrongNameFreeBuffer([In] IntPtr pbMemory);

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.PreserveSig | MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
    int StrongNameGetBlob([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] [In] string pwzFilePath, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 2)] [Out] byte[] pbBlob, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] [In] [Out] ref int pcbBlob);

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.PreserveSig | MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
    int StrongNameGetBlobFromImage([In] IntPtr pbBase, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] [In] int dwLength, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 3)] [Out] byte[] pbBlob, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] [In] [Out] ref int pcbBlob);

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.PreserveSig | MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
    int StrongNameGetPublicKey([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] [In] string pwzKeyContainer, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 2)] [In] byte[] pbKeyBlob, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] [In] int cbKeyBlob, out IntPtr ppbPublicKeyBlob, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] out int pcbPublicKeyBlob);

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.PreserveSig | MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    int StrongNameHashSize([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] [In] int ulHashAlg, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] out int cbSize);

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.PreserveSig | MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
    int StrongNameKeyDelete([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] [In] string pwzKeyContainer);

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.PreserveSig | MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
    int StrongNameKeyGen([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] [In] string pwzKeyContainer, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] [In] int dwFlags, out IntPtr ppbKeyBlob, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] out int pcbKeyBlob);

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.PreserveSig | MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
    int StrongNameKeyGenEx([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] [In] string pwzKeyContainer, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] [In] int dwFlags, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] [In] int dwKeySize, out IntPtr ppbKeyBlob, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] out int pcbKeyBlob);

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.PreserveSig | MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
    int StrongNameKeyInstall([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] [In] string pwzKeyContainer, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 2)] [In] byte[] pbKeyBlob, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] [In] int cbKeyBlob);

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.PreserveSig | MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
    int StrongNameSignatureGeneration([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] [In] string pwzFilePath, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] [In] string pwzKeyContainer, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 3)] [In] byte[] pbKeyBlob, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] [In] int cbKeyBlob, [In] [Out] IntPtr ppbSignatureBlob, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] out int pcbSignatureBlob);

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.PreserveSig | MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
    int StrongNameSignatureGenerationEx([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] [In] string wszFilePath, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] [In] string wszKeyContainer, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 3)] [In] byte[] pbKeyBlob, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] [In] int cbKeyBlob, [In] [Out] IntPtr ppbSignatureBlob, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] out int pcbSignatureBlob, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] [In] int dwFlags);

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.PreserveSig | MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
    int StrongNameSignatureSize([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 1)] [In] byte[] pbPublicKeyBlob, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] [In] int cbPublicKeyBlob, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] out int pcbSize);

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.PreserveSig | MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    int StrongNameSignatureVerification([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] [In] string pwzFilePath, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] [In] int dwInFlags, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] out int dwOutFlags);

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.PreserveSig | MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    int StrongNameSignatureVerificationEx([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] [In] string pwzFilePath, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)] [In] bool fForceVerification, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)] out bool fWasVerified);

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.PreserveSig | MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    int StrongNameSignatureVerificationFromImage([In] IntPtr pbBase, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] [In] int dwLength, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] [In] int dwInFlags, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] out int dwOutFlags);

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.PreserveSig | MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
    int StrongNameTokenFromAssembly([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] [In] string pwzFilePath, out IntPtr ppbStrongNameToken, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] out int pcbStrongNameToken);

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.PreserveSig | MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
    int StrongNameTokenFromAssemblyEx([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] [In] string pwzFilePath, out IntPtr ppbStrongNameToken, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] out int pcbStrongNameToken, out IntPtr ppbPublicKeyBlob, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] out int pcbPublicKeyBlob);

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.PreserveSig | MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
    int StrongNameTokenFromPublicKey([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 1)] [In] byte[] pbPublicKeyBlob, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] [In] int cbPublicKeyBlob, out IntPtr ppbStrongNameToken, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] out int pcbStrongNameToken);
}
```

Comment: Fantastic help. Works nicely for me. Thanks you very much

Comment: You saved my life. Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

There's little point in testing the strong name after the assembly got loaded. An attacker could simply inject a module constructor in the assembly and execute any code desired. The .NET 3.5 SP1 version of the framework followed suit and is no longer verifying the strong name of assemblies that get loaded from trusted locations. Startup times improve by about 40%.

The key point is: once an attacker compromises the machine to a point where he is able to inject an assembly in the probing path of your application, he won't bother doing it the hard way. He'd just replace your EXE file.

Comment: Actually this is a situation where extensions (in the form of assemblies) can be added to the application i.e they are loaded from a directory using Assembly.LoadFile and I only want to be able to load extensions which have been signed with the same strong name as the host application.

Comment: So this isn't a case of safe-guarding an entire system or application, but restricting whom is able to write extensions to the application itself. No strong name, sorry your extension will not be loaded

Comment: @Hans Passant I think testing strong name is still useful. If exe A references dll B and both are strong named, and strong name validation is enabled in app.config, then a hacker may simply remove strong name on both files via some hacking file level (byte) overwriting. We can check in program start that if the assembly has any strong name (i.e signed)