# How to use StrongNameSignatureVerificationFromImage?

Tags: .net, winapi

This method, while "documented", just doesn't seem to work for me.
I'm trying to verify the signature of the currently running executable. Used `GetModuleHandle` as the first param (base address) and `GetModuleInformation` to find the size.
I keep getting back `CORSEC_E_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT`.
I also thought maybe the method expects the address of the manifest, so I use `FindResource` etc to get that address, but it didn't work either.
Has anyone successfully used this method?

Sample code:

```
HMODULE modHandle = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
MODULEINFO modInfo;
GetModuleInformation(GetCurrentProcess(), modHandle, &modInfo, sizeof(MODULEINFO));
DWORD temp;
BOOL valid = StrongNameSignatureVerificationFromImage((BYTE*)modHandle, modInfo.SizeOfImage, 0, &temp);
DWORD res = StrongNameErrorInfo(); // returns CORSEC_E_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT
```

Comment: this method is deprecated as per documentation. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms231929%28v=vs.100%29.aspx. Also I think the method needs the assembly to be already mapped into the application's memory. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I tried the new version of this method as well. Same result.
The assembly I'm trying to verify is that of the executing process. It's obviously mapped into memory.
I'm writing a library that needs to verify it's being executed from a process with a signed assembly.

Comment: Digitally signed or strong named?

Comment: Strong named.
Also see this article:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2004/06/07/150378.aspx
Same idea, only I want to use the memory mapped image as opposed to accessing the assembly from disk.

Comment: Try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308756/checking-an-assembly-for-a-strong-name and this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/27a5b126-bdb4-4d67-8cdb-f6601e171e73/how-to-verify-strong-name-programmatically-in-cnet-4?forum=clr. Did not try them, but they seem helpful

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't answer my question.
I'd like to use this method because:
1. It verifies the signature (as opposed to just reading the public key).
2. It can (supposedly) do that without file system access.
If that wasn't a requirement I would have just used StrongNameSignatureVerificationEx as demonstrated in the MSDN blog post.

Comment: Do you have a sample code reproducing your problem?

Comment: @Mike Just so that I understand, is the above code C++ / C++ CLI? If yes, what is the hosting executable C# or C++ or C++ CLI?

Comment: C++ CLI. Hosting executable is a C# WPF app.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I was able to come up with regarding to `Assembly`, using the **AutoPiner** class from this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/23838643/6694311) :

```
var fileStream= assembly.GetFile( assembly.ManifestModule.Name );
var byteArray = new byte[]{};
using(var ms = new MemoryStream()){
    fileStream.CopyTo(ms);
    byteArray = ms.ToArray();
}
var result = false;
using( var gcPinned = new AutoPinner( byteArray ) ) {
    try {
        int outFlags;
        result = HResult.S_OK == (HResult)ICLRStrongName.StrongNameSignatureVerificationFromImage( gcPinned, byteArray.Length, NativeMethods.SN_INFLAG_FORCE_VER, out outFlags )
                   && ( outFlags & NativeMethods.SN_OUTFLAG_WAS_VERIFIED ) == NativeMethods.SN_OUTFLAG_WAS_VERIFIED;
    } catch {
        result = false;
    }
}
```

Where **NativeMethods** is:

```
internal static class NativeMethods
{
    /// <summary>
    /// https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff844053(v=vs.110).aspx
    /// ICLRStrongName::StrongNameSignatureVerificationFromImage
    /// </summary>

    //Forces verification even if it is necessary to override registry settings
    public const int SN_INFLAG_FORCE_VER = 0x1;

    //Specifies that this is the first verification performed on this image
    public const int SN_INFLAG_INSTALL = 0x2;

    //Specifies that the cache will allow access only to users who have administrative privileges
    public const int SN_INFLAG_ADMIN_ACCESS = 0x4;

    //Specifies that the assembly will be accessible only to the current user
    public const int SN_INFLAG_USER_ACCESS = 0x8;

    //Specifies that the cache will provide no guarantees of access restriction
    public const int SN_INFLAG_ALL_ACCESS = 0x10;

    //This value is set to false to specify that the verification succeeded due to registry settings
    public const int SN_OUTFLAG_WAS_VERIFIED = 0x1;
}
```

With a little more catch clauses and some exception message parsing you can have other than `bool` result.